# How do I stretch a background SVG so it always fills a div via CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have searched all over this website for an answer to this question.
I need to make a `background image` completely fill a `div` at all times. The `image` has `edges` around it that are textured so they must stay within the screen when I scroll in and out and not be cut off. The `image` must also always cover the `width` of the page and the `height` of the `div`.

Here is what I have found and tried (none of which have been successful):

- Using `background-size: 100% 100%;` 
  This does not work as when I scroll in and out the image keeps its resolution and no longer covers the entire div that stretches. (Even changing the values still doesn't work.)
- Using `background-size: cover;`
  This does not work because first of all it cuts off the left and right sides of the `image` when normal and then when I scroll out it cuts out the top and bottom.
- I have also tried using `img` tags inside the `div` and styled them however I started having a problem where the `image` was only a thin outline.

What I actually want to do is make `CSS` stretch the `image` to cover the width of the page but keep the height of the div. I understand this will distort the image and I am fine with that. Is there a way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
div.two {
    position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1111px;
    background-image: url("Task 7 body 1.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Here are some images as requested;

[This is with `background-size: 100% 100%;` and default zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBgHS.png)

[This is with `background-size: cover;` and default zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QKlP.png)

Unfortunately I can not post more than 2 links so I hope that helps.

As you can see, with `background-size: 100% 100%;` it is exactly how I would like it when on default zoom however when scrolling out, the `width` of the `image` reduces to keep the same ratio. When scrolling in, the `height` of the `image` reduces to keep the same ratio.

When using `background-size: cover;` on default zoom the left and right edges are cut off which is a problem. When zooming in, it still cuts off the left and right however fills the `div`. When scrolling out, it cuts off the top and bottom edges however fills the `div`.

I want it to fill the `div` but do not want it to cut off the edges.

Comment: can you show some visual of your Output / error

Comment: It's not as simple as it looks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Scaling_of_SVG_backgrounds

Comment: I have edited my post a bit to show photos of my problem as requested. I have had a look through that link and unfortunately couldn't find the solution. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I have just tried opening the html in IE and it has worked exactly how I want it to. I have been using Chrome and having problems. Maybe Chrome isn't the best option as I have faced other problems with it too. Is there any solution to Chrome not performing properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the way the SVG scales when it is rendered as an image.

Open up your SVG file and add the following attribute to the root (ie outermost / first) `<svg>` tag in the file.

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

If there is already a `preserveAspectRatio` attribute there, then change it's value to `"none"`.

Comment: Ah yes! That has done it. Works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That works fine but not in the FF, do you have any thought?

looks like FF ignores `preserveAspectRatio`

Comment: @vicodin It should be working. If it's not, then open a new question and post an example.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to give min-width:100%

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this with a few different variables and it still isn't what I am after. It still cuts off the edges as I scroll in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the background `background-attachment:fixed;`,

```
div.two {
    position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1111px;
    background-image: url("Task 7 body 1.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed; //fix it to background
}
```

No matter, how much width/height of the div is. The Image will stretch to full width and height of it.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem I face here is that the top and bottom of the image are cut off and the width is reduced even though I have it set at 100%. Not to mention that when moving up and down the page the background moves with it. Thanks for you help anyway.